# Apache mod_authnz_ldap: Is it possible to connect via Unix domain socket file?

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap

On my Debian server I have configured the LDAP server `slapd` to accept connections only via Unix domain socket file. This is the relevant part from `/etc/defaults/slapd`:

```
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldapi:///"
```

I have been happily living with this configuration, all sorts of PHP applications are nicely working with it. Now I am trying to configure Apache to authenticate via LDAP. I am doing this via the core module `mod_authnz_ldap`. Naively using the `ldapi` URL scheme doesn't work:

```
AuthLDAPUrl ldapi:///ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
```

All I am seeing in the Apache error are TCP connection attempts to `localhost:389` and `127.0.0.1:389`, which are, of course, all refused because no one is listening on this port. I also tried two more URLs, both with the same negative result:

```
# Same as the 1st attempt, but with ldap:// instead of ldapi://
AuthLDAPUrl ldap:///ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)

# Getting desperate: Specify the file path of the Unix domain socket file
AuthLDAPUrl ldap:///var/run/slapd/ldapi/ou=users,dc=herzbube,dc=ch?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
```

The [Apache 2.4 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl) for `AuthLDAPUrl` state this:

> An RFC 2255 URL which specifies the LDAP search parameters to use.

[RFC 2255](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2255.txt) indeed does not mention the `ldapi` URL scheme, nor of any way how to specify a Unix domain socket file path.

Did I overlook something? Does anyone know how I can get `mod_authnz_ldap` to use the Unix domain socket file for connections? Or is it indeed, as I fear, impossible to do this with `mod_authnz_ldap`?

My setup:

- Debian jessie
- Apache 2.4.10
- OpenLDAP 2.4.40
- Unix domain socket file `/var/run/slapd/ldapi` is readable by web server user `www-data`

Comment: I fear it is not supported by `mod_authnz_ldap`, as the exact behaviour you are facing is described here https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44302

Comment: @krisFR Thanks for digging this up. If you write this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid it is not supported by directive `AuthLDAPURL` from module `mod_authnz_ldap`.

At least at the time i wrote these lines.

A bug track report has been published and describes exactly the behaviour you are facing :

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44302

> if you enter ldapi:///, it is (silently) treated as
>   ldap://localhost:389, that is, the connection is still done over TCP
>   to localhost